# How to check which element occur first selenium

Tags: python, selenium

What is the cleanest way to detect which selenium element occur first in python?

Example:

```
elem1 = driver.find_element(By.ID, "tos")
elem1 = driver.find_element(By.ID, "policy")

if elem1 occur first:
    do_something()
else:
    do_something()
```

**Edit**:
Usually `webdriverwait().until` method wait for one element, what i want is to use `webdriverwait().until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located(elem1 or elem2)`

Comment: By occur do you mean load first or appear higher up in the page?

Answer (score 0):

if there is anything different like you can print like

```
       print elem1.text
       print elem1.tag_name
       print elem1.parent
       print elem1.location
       print elem1.size


elem1 = driver.find_element(By.ID, "tos")
elem1 = driver.find_element(By.ID, "policy")

if elem1 occur first:
    do_something()
   print elem1.text    // like if text is different
else:
    do_something()


print elem1.parent  // like if parent element is different
```